# Define thousand of products in several languages in a sitemap

Tags: sitemap, product

I've got an online shop with more than 70.000 products. In a few months we will have more than 200.000 products.
Every product has its own url depending on the language, for example:

- domain.com/es/aaabbbcccc/product_code
- domain.com/en/aaabbbcccc/product_code
- domain.com/fr/aaabbbcccc/product_code
- domain.com/pt/aaabbbcccc/product_code
- domain.com/de/aaabbbcccc/product_code

All those url redirect to the same page but the language depends on the "es", "en", etc.

We want Google to index the sitemap so it knows all of our products so they can be found using Google Search.

I've been reading about sitemaps and if I'm not wrong, they should contain all available url in a webpage, but I know we cannot put 5 url for every product because that would get one millions urls.

Should I define just one url for every product, which would generate thousands of urls? Or is there any way to tell Google the format of a url so it is not necessary to explicitly define all of them?

Comment: Why is 1,000,000 URL a problem but 200,000 is not?

Comment: 200.000 is also a problem, but the minimum urls would be that number, but there may be another way to define them to avoid so many url.